# Looking for a word that means coming from two diverse places

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I have a background in fiction writing and creative event planning as well as in business operations in international shipping. I want a word that could help me describe my background.

With my ____ background, I possess a unique skillset that lies at the intersection of business development and creativity.

Something like cross-industrial? but hoping for another word

Comment: **versatile** is a word that suggests you have a *variety* of skills and different kinds of experience to draw on. It wouldn't modify your background, but yourself, as a result of your **varied** background.

Comment: What do you mean by *two diverse places* here? Do you mean something like *two different places, two distinct places, two separate places*? If so, I would write one of those others here instead.

Answer (score 2):

With my **eclectic** background, I possess a unique skillset that lies at the intersection of business development and creativity.

[fiction writing is not an "industry"]

ADJECTIVE
An eclectic collection of objects, ideas, or beliefs is wide-ranging and comes from many different sources.
[formal]
...an eclectic collection of paintings, drawings, and prints.
Synonyms: diverse, general, broad, varied

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/eclectic)

Comment: @Conrado Thanks. I fixed it. [Do you know São Conrado in Rio?]

Comment: No, I never heard of it before. It looks like a spiffy place! "Oh I want to go down to Río before I die." Now I have to add it to my list of places to go sometime... I live on the other side of the continent and further South, in [Puerto Octay](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Octay).

Comment: Well, I was raised right near there. There were no tall apt. buildings at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You might search for synonyms of "diverse". Many sites will offer many words, and the sets don't always overlap.
One example:
[Power Thesaurus "heterogeneous"](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/heterogeneous/synonyms)
diverse, varied, mixed, motley, assorted, et al.
(see link)

Just search in Google '"diverse" synonyms' .

Answer (score 0):

To underline that your experience is in *two diverse areas*, I suggest:

> With my **dual background**, I possess a unique skillset that lies at
> the intersection of business development and creativity.

> **dual** (adj.)
>
> Consisting of two parts or elements or having two like parts
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dual)

---

> The two editors embody the international and multidisciplinary nature
> required for such an endeavor. Martine, who is a British-French dual
> national, has a **dual background** in criminal law and in
> criminology, while Massil has a **dual background** in psychology and
> criminology.
> [Martine Herzog-Evans, Massil Benbouriche;
> *Evidence-Based Work with Violent Extremists*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DQmkDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22has%20a%20dual%20background%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAweyqmt6CAxX5KFkFHe5iDjAQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22has%20a%20dual%20background%22&f=false) (2019)

Many other [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20a%20dual%20backgroun%22&sca_esv=585174118&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKk_iW9paWejYskGr4-ckK_znwppLw%3A1700882820970&ei=hGlhZb7hOsmv5NoP8qq90AM&ved=0ahUKEwi-s-Simt6CAxXJF1kFHXJVDzoQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22has%20a%20dual%20backgroun%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhYiaGFzIGEgZHVhbCBiYWNrZ3JvdW4iSPsOUN0GWIMMcAB4AJABAJgBaKABhgWqAQM1LjK4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgQQIRgKiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) of *dual background* can be found with Google Books.

---